# Create unique array while push Object to array in react useState hook

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, multidimensional-array, use-state

I am declaring react state as below

```
const [selectedFiles, setselectedFiles] = useState([]);
```

Using them in function as below

```
function handleAcceptedFiles(files) {
    files.map((file) =>
      Object.assign(file, {
        preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
        formattedSize: file.size,
      })
    );
    selectedFiles.length === 0 ? setselectedFiles(files) : setselectedFiles(oldFiles => [...oldFiles,...files])
  }
```

At this point how can we add only new file and remove duplicate file

```
setselectedFiles(oldFiles => [...oldFiles,...files])
```

Comment: does `files` includes `oldFiles`'s elements, or just new elements only?

Comment: just new elements

Comment: you should also provide example of a file element

Comment: *just new elements* so why you worry about removing duplicated files?

Comment: In new element may be he select same files then it will add duplicate files

Comment: as I see, each file is object, so is there any property to detect whether it is unique or not, maybe filename or something?

Comment: preview: URL.createObjectURL(file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a lookup object with key-value pairs of filePreview-file and grab `values` from that

```
function handleAcceptedFiles(files) {
  const pendingFiles = files.map(file =>
    Object.assign(file, {
      preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
      formattedSize: file.size
    })
  )

  const dedupFiles = Object.values(
    [...selectedFiles, ...pendingFiles].reduce((lookup, file) => {
      if (lookup[file.name] === undefined) {
        lookup[file.name] = file
      }
      return lookup
    }, {})
  )

  setselectedFiles(dedupFiles)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you need?

```
function handleAcceptedFiles(files) {
  // Map over the current selection of files, generate required fields
  const newFiles = files.map(file => {
    return Object.assign(file, {
      preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
      formattedSize: file.size,
    });
  });

  // Find non-duplicate entries in previously selected files
  const nonDupFiles = selectedFiles.filter(oldFile => {
    const index = newFiles.findIndex(newFile => newFile.preview === oldFile.preview);
    return index === -1;  // index -1 => file wasn't found => non duplicate
  });

  // Concat of new files and non-dup files is what we need in state
  setselectedFiles(newFiles.concat(nonDupFiles));
}
```